# Python multithreading design suggestions

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a question regarding my current threading design -- my current process spawns a new thread and continues the main thread until the termination condition.  The process waits until all threads finish before terminating.  The issue I am having is that each new thread spawned needs to see if the previous thread spawned is done.  Should I simply set up a queue and use just one thread to process all the tasks?  Or is it possible to spawn a thread, somehow check if the previous thread is done and process the task only once that thread in question is done?

thanks for your help

Comment: An aside: you should know/read about the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) which can significantly impact the effectiveness of multi-threaded CPython applications

Answer (score 4):

If all of the threads aside from the initial "main" thread are supposed to run sequentially, then yes, you should use a task queue and a single worker thread.

[`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) can help with this (and allow your main thread to `.join()` on it if it needs to wait for all of the queued tasks to be completed).

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Gevent](http://gevent.org/).
You can create several Greenlet objects for your several tasks.
Each greenlet is [green thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads).

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
import gevent
from gevent import Greenlet

class Task(Greenlet):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Greenlet.__init__(self)
        self.name = name    
    def _run(self):
        print "Task %s: some task..." % self.name

t1 = Task("task1")
t2 = Task("task2")
t1.start()
t2.start()
# here we are waiting all tasks
gevent.joinall([t1,t2])
```